# I need to include orcid ID in Latex beside the author affiliation, I tried many time, but it doesn't work

Tags: fonts, xetex, luatex, academicons

```
\documentclass{svproc}

\usepackage{url}
\def\UrlFont{\rmfamily}

\usepackage{academicons}
\newcommand{\orcid}[1]{\href{https://orcid.org/#1}{\textcolor[HTML]{A6CE39}{\aiOrcid}}}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter             
\title{The title}
%
\titlerunning{abbreviated title}  

\author{Ivar Ekeland\inst{1} \and Roger Temam\inst{2}\orcid{0000-0002-5825-931X}}

\institute{XXX University\\
\email{email@email.edu},
\and
YYYY University,\\
\email{email@email.edu}}

\maketitle              % typeset the title of the contribution

\begin{abstract}
The abstract 
\keywords{}
\end{abstract}

\section{Section 1}


\begin{thebibliography}{6}

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please clarify what “but it doesn’t work” entails. Do you get any error or earring messages? If so, what do they say?

Comment: Incidentally, why is `\mainmatter` the first instruction after `\begin{document}`?

Comment: I downloaded LaTeX templates from the journal's site, it contains this line "\mainmatter"

Comment: “but it doesn’t work” I mean that, it gives error and orcid logo doesn’t appear in the pdf file

Comment: And what does the error message say?

Comment: Undefined control sequence.

Comment: I have used these
\usepackage{academicons}
\newcommand{\orcid}[1]{\href{https://orcid.org/#1}{\textcolor[HTML]{A6CE39}{\aiOrcid}}}
and placed this order \orcid{0000-0002-5825-931X} beside \inst{2}
I do not know this is right or wrong

Comment: Incidentally, does the `Undefined control sequence` message point to `\href` as being undefined? If so, it's because your document isn't loading the `hyperref` package with suitable options.

Comment: Undefined control sequence. point to  \maketitle

Answer (score 4):

Your test document cannot work because the definition of the `\orcid` macro contains the directives `\textcolor` and `\href`, which are defined by the `xcolor` and `hyperref` packages, respectively. Hence, you *must* load both `xcolor` and `hyperref` -- with suitably chosen options, if needed -- for `\orcid` to work.

Moreover, be sure to compile your document with either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, as that's what is *required* by the `academicons` package. To quote from the package's user guide: "The `academicons` package provides access in (LA)TEX to 122 high quality icons of online academic profiles included in the free *Academicons* font. This package requires either the XƎ(LA)TEX or Lua(LA)TEX engine to load the *Academicons* font from the system, which requires installing the bundled `academicons.ttf` font file."

The following simplified form of your test code compiles fine. (However, I have no way of telling whether the hyperlink embedded in the icon works.)

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex  %% or: "... = lualatex"
\documentclass{svproc}
% 'svproc.cls' file obtained from https://www.springer.com/gp/authors-editors/conference-proceedings/conference-proceedings-guidelines
\usepackage{xurl}
\def\UrlFont{\rmfamily}

\usepackage{xcolor} % for 'HTML' color model and '\textcolor' macro
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref} % for '\href' macro

% 'academicons' package requires either LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX
\usepackage{academicons} 
\newcommand{\orcid}[1]{\href{orcid.org/#1}{\textcolor[HTML]{A6CE39}{\aiOrcid}}}

\begin{document}
\orcid{0000-0002-5825-931X} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much